# Not able to implement Native Video ads through Manual Integration in android using Mopub

Tags: android, video, native, ads, mopub

As the Documentation of **Mopub** say's [here](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/native-video/#manual-integration) ,integrated the Native ads and followed by Native Video ads.

After integrating the code the ad request response is calling the callback method `onNativeFail()` 
with some of the response

**Below code is related to the workflow and logcat message**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private MoPubView moPubView;
//private MoPubInterstitial mInterstitial;
private MoPubNative moPubNative;
private MoPubNativeNetworkListener moPubNativeNetworkListener;
private NativeAd.MoPubNativeEventListener moPubNativeEventListener;
AdapterHelper adapterHelper;
private NativeFullScreenVideoView nativeFullScreenVideoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moPubNativeNetworkListener = new MoPubNativeNetworkListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNativeLoad(NativeAd nativeAd) {
            Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad has loaded.");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNativeFail(NativeErrorCode errorCode) {
            Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad failed to load with error: " + errorCode.toString());
        }
    };

    moPubNativeEventListener = new NativeAd.MoPubNativeEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImpression(View view) {
            Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad recorded an impression.");
            // Impress is recorded - do what is needed AFTER the ad is visibly shown here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("MoPub", "Native ad recorded a click.");
            // Click tracking.
        }
    };

    moPubNative = new MoPubNative(this, "02a2d288d2674ad09f3241d46a44356e ", moPubNativeNetworkListener);

    ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_ad_list_item)
            .mainImageId(R.id.native_main_image)
            .iconImageId(R.id.native_icon_image)
            .titleId(R.id.native_title)
            .textId(R.id.native_text)
            .privacyInformationIconImageId(R.id.native_privacy_information_icon_image)
            .build();


    MediaViewBinder mediaViewBinder = new MediaViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_video_ad_layout)
            .mediaLayoutId(R.id.native_ad_video_view)
            .iconImageId(R.id.native_ad_icon_image)
            .titleId(R.id.native_ad_title)
            .textId(R.id.native_ad_text)
            .build();

    MoPubVideoNativeAdRenderer moPubVideoNativeAdRenderer = new MoPubVideoNativeAdRenderer(mediaViewBinder);
    moPubNative.registerAdRenderer(moPubVideoNativeAdRenderer);


    MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer = new MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(viewBinder);
    moPubNative.registerAdRenderer(moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer);


    EnumSet<RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset> desiredAssets = EnumSet.of(
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.TITLE,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.TEXT,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.CALL_TO_ACTION_TEXT,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.MAIN_IMAGE,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.ICON_IMAGE,
            RequestParameters.NativeAdAsset.STAR_RATING
    );

    RequestParameters mRequestParameters = new RequestParameters.Builder()
            .desiredAssets(desiredAssets)
            .build();

    moPubNative.makeRequest();

}
```

}

After running this code, the ad is not getting loaded and the response of my code is below

```
06-06 17:01:41.797 24421-24421/? I/Ads: Webview loading for native ads.
06-06 17:01:41.911 24421-24421/? I/Ads: Javascript has loaded for native ads.
06-06 17:02:18.623 24421-24421/? I/Ads: Webview loading for native ads.
06-06 17:02:18.954 24421-24421/? I/Ads: Javascript has loaded for native ads.
06-06 17:02:51.796 13278-13278/com.fabgrad.students.android D/MoPub: Native ad request failed.
                                                                 com.mopub.network.MoPubNetworkError: No ads found for ad unit.
                                                                     at com.mopub.network.AdRequest.parseNetworkResponse(AdRequest.java:180)
                                                                     at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
                                                                     at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
06-06 17:02:51.800 13278-13278/com.fabgrad.students.android D/MoPub: Native ad failed to load with error: Server returned empty response.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per their blog, No ads found will come for following scenarios:

These errors indicate that there was no fill for your ad unit.
No ad network will have fill 100% of the time, so seeing this log is normal. New apps and apps with very low volume tend to experience lower fill rates. Contact your ad network representative if you have any concerns related to a particular network’s fill.

If you are consistently seeing no fill, review your ad network placement details in the Networks tab of the MoPub UI, as well as your settings in the Network’s UI.

You won’t be able to show ads from Certified Ad Networks if you forgot to include the network SDK or adapter files. The Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event and Unable to find Native Network or Custom Event adapter log messages are indicators that the network SDK or adapter file is missing, renamed, or in the wrong location.

**Review our Integrating Third-Party Ad Networks documentation to resolve this.**

[Link](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/test/) for reference.